# crop image (first 200px vertically) and save it php

Tags: php

I have an image:

`/files/image.jpg`

this image has `1000x1000 px`.
I want to crop and save it to has 800px vertically and keep the horizontal width (in example image 1000 but may change).

Can anyone give me an example to use `imagecrop` or any function to this? and then save this file in `/files/image.jpg` replacing the original one?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script

https://github.com/jamiebicknell/Thumb

set size=1000x800
and align=t